# Android adds gab to the edit text when using gravity in it

Tags: android, xml, right-to-left, gravity

I made an edit text and it was working very well, but when I added right gravity to the *editText*, the *editText* height increased. I tried to set *paddingBottom* to zero, but that didn't work.

This is my code:

```
    <EditText
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/new_et"
        android:hint="البريد الالكترونى"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingHorizontal="5dp" />
```

Comment: please show us your whole XML code and screenshots to understand more

Comment: I can't upload image to the question

Answer (score 0):

If your minSdkVersion is less than 17, you should add both the older left/right attributes as well as the new start/right attributes.

```
    `android:gravity="end" and  android:gravity="right"` for SDK < 17 and 
     android:gravity="end" for SDK >=17.
```

And also try to check with the drawable which is set as background because when we are setting the height as wrap_content it may take the drawable properties.